# How to do iterative quicksort without using stack in c?

Tags: c

First of all does C have a stack class?

Second How can I do a method to do quicksort in C without using stack and recursion?

If there is no way to do it without stack can you give me a code for it?

Comment: 1. No. 2. Huh?? 3. No

Comment: Remember stack is kept on recursive  function calls, that might be the direction you'll like to dig in more depth. Stacks can be implemented without the native stack frames provided by function calls.

Comment: C does not have classes at all.  If you want classes, then C++ is a couple of doors down.

Comment: ok how can I run c++ code inside c code. I heard that I can do that by using something like:-                                                                                 using namespace foo;
using namespace bar;

Comment: More generally, because Quicksort works by repeatedly splitting the input array into two pieces, and then splitting each of those pieces, etc., you cannot write Quicksort without a means to track, for each step, the boundaries of the second sub-array that needs to be processed .  That requires a data structure functionally equivalent to a stack.

Comment: I understand that but there was an argument about all recursive method can be written in an iterative way. Why we can't do this method without recursion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First of all does C have a stack class?

C does not provide a stack class, that's up to you to code.

> Second How can I do a method to do quicksort in C without using stack and recursion?

Searching through the internet I found this guy that made a non recursive, non stack quicksort. Looks pretty compact so be careful when reading. Here's the [link](http://alienryderflex.com/quicksort/).

> If there is no way to do it without stack can you give me a code for it?

This one I think is already aswered.

Comment: Well, borderline to answer such question. I've done merely the same giving a comment (I'm well aware of you can't comment yet).