# Is there a Python implementation of quicksort without recursion?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, quicksort

I am attempting to implement quick sort in Python without using recursion, but all reference implementations or pseudo codes I have found so far use recursion.

The reason for this is that I will adapt this non-recursive implementation to run on GPUs using Numba, and I cannot make recursive calls there.

Is there a quick sort implementation for a 1d array (say, a Numpy array or Python list) that does not use recursion?

Thanks,

Eduardo

Comment: At its heart, recursion is nothing more than a convenient way to manage a stack.  Anything that can be implemented with recursion can also be implemented non-recursively with an explicitly managed stack.  In Python, you can use a list for the stack.  The code generally isn't as clear, but it doesn't need to be that much worse either.  Whenever you would make a recursive call, push push the state needed to resume your current call onto the stack.  Whenever you would return recursively, pop and restore that state from the stack.

Comment: It should be a fairly simple exercise to convert a standard recursive quicksort into one that uses a stack to manage its state.  You need to save the low and high bounds, and the pivot index.  Then you can loop instead of recursing.  Set the bounds to the first partition, loop, and restore your context.  Then set the bounds to the second partition, loop, and restore your context.  That's about all you need to do.

Comment: Another possibility is to use heapsort, which doesn't require recursion or a stack.  It's also an O(n\*log(n)) sort algorithm.  Its average case performance is a little worse than quicksort, but it worst-case performance is still O(n\*log(n)), unlike quicksort which can be worse than O(n\*log(n)) in the worst case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, this is a Python version:

```
# This function is same in both iterative and recursive
def partition(arr,l,h):
    i = ( l - 1 )
    x = arr[h]
  
    for j in range(l , h):
        if   arr[j] <= x:
  
            # increment index of smaller element
            i = i+1
            arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]
  
    arr[i+1],arr[h] = arr[h],arr[i+1]
    return (i+1)
  
# Function to do Quick sort
# arr[] --> Array to be sorted,
# l  --> Starting index,
# h  --> Ending index
def quickSortIterative(arr,l,h):
  
    # Create an auxiliary stack
    size = h - l + 1
    stack = [0] * (size)
  
    # initialize top of stack
    top = -1
  
    # push initial values of l and h to stack
    top = top + 1
    stack[top] = l
    top = top + 1
    stack[top] = h
  
    # Keep popping from stack while is not empty
    while top >= 0:
  
        # Pop h and l
        h = stack[top]
        top = top - 1
        l = stack[top]
        top = top - 1
  
        # Set pivot element at its correct position in
        # sorted array
        p = partition( arr, l, h )
  
        # If there are elements on left side of pivot,
        # then push left side to stack
        if p-1 > l:
            top = top + 1
            stack[top] = l
            top = top + 1
            stack[top] = p - 1
  
        # If there are elements on right side of pivot,
        # then push right side to stack
        if p+1 < h:
            top = top + 1
            stack[top] = p + 1
            top = top + 1
            stack[top] = h
  
# Driver code to test above
arr = [4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3]
n = len(arr)
quickSortIterative(arr, 0, n-1)
print ("Sorted array is:")
for i in range(n):
    print ("%d" %arr[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard unix/linux qsort is implemented without recursion for efficiency. You could look that up, or just translate the code in this answer to python:

[Can quicksort be implemented in C without stack and recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008384/can-quicksort-be-implemented-in-c-without-stack-and-recursion/55010206)

Comment: All of the posted code in that question uses a stack (in fact, only one answer contains code, and it explicitly mentions that it uses a bounded stack with 1000 elements, implemented as two arrays, and notes that it is unacceptable).  The accepted answer, on the other hand, references a paper that claims to use no stack, but the code is not present in the post.

Comment: Nope. The code by chqrlie uses no stack, and has no problems.

Comment: Both `beg[MAX_LEVELS]` and `end[MAX_LEVELS]` are arrays that are used as stacks.  The function uses two fixed-size arrays, which bound the size of the largest array it can sort, and it uses them as stacks.  Further, they both reside on the *call stack*, although that hardly matters.  The original code used 1000-element stacks, and the poster modified it to use 64-element stacks.  But in either case, the amount of stack needed grows with the size of the input array, which is capped based on the fixed-size stacks in the implementation.  The poster makes that very clear.

Comment: The point is that none of those implementations scale up to arbitrarily large input arrays, the way a true O(1) implementation would.  In practice, that might not matter, but from an algorithmic standpoint, they are not O(1), a fact that the poster clearly acknowledges.